# What accents pronounce "quarter" as "korter"? Which other words can drop /w/ before /ɔr/ like this?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, dialects, phonology, accent

Many people drop the "w" from words like "dwarf," changing the pronunciation from /dwɔrf/ to /dɔrf/. This has led to the re-spelling "dorf" being used in some informal contexts, e.g. "[Dorf Fort](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Dorf%20Fort)."

My question is not just about this one word, though. This change seems to be part of a broader sound change that is currently in progress where "w" is sometimes dropped when preceded by a consonant and followed by the sound /ɔr/. Another example is "quarter" /kwɔrtər/ being pronounced as /kɔrtər/. (See these threads from the American Dialect Society mailing list: [/kw/~/k/](http://listserv.linguistlist.org/pipermail/ads-l/2000-April/005973.html), [quarter](http://listserv.linguistlist.org/pipermail/ads-l/2000-April/006053.html), and this one from alt.usage.english: [Quarter](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Alt/alt.usage.english/2012-09/msg02507.html)). I know there are several older sound changes that caused /w/ to drop in similar positions in the past, such as in "two" and "sword," but I'm asking specifically about the most recent sound change, which affects words that have pronunciations with /w/ listed in modern dictionaries.

I have this sound change, but only optionally and only in some words. I can pronounce "dwarf" as /dwɔrf/ or /dɔrf/, and "quarter" as /kwɔrtər/ or /kɔrtər/, but I can only pronounce "thwart" as /θwɔrt/, not as /θɔrt/. I'm trying to figure out why this difference exists.

This sound change seems to be recent and currently in progress, so I also wanted to learn where it exists. Some sources seem to indicate that it mainly occurs in North American accents. For example, the Oxford English dictionary entry for "dwarf" gives the British pronunciation as /dwɔːf/, and the U.S. pronunciation as /d(w)ɔrf/. However, the author of the alt.usage.english post I referenced above describes hearing the pronunciation "KOR-ter" for "quarter" from a BBC reporter, who I would assume was British. So I'm really not sure! Does anyone know more about this sound change, where it is most common, and what words it tends to affect?

---

I think it's more common with words like "quarter" than with words like "dwarf," so it seems I chose a bad example with my original title. However, for the disbelievers, I have looked up Youtube videos that contain this pronunciation of "dwarf":

- [LOTRO Classes - Classes of LOTRO](https://youtu.be/ms3Xr0zDmlk?t=3m), see 3:04, 4:25, 5:30
- [Minecraft Mod Showcase: More Player Models!](http://[1.3.2]https://youtu.be/oNrrZQmNyVI?t=29s), see 0:29
- [Lords of Uberdark - Lords of Uberdark Alpha 40 - More Dorfs! - VerbalProcessing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRYYpUy94mY&feature=youtu.be&t=6m00s)

Not a lot, I know. So if you think this pronunciation doesn't exist, just focus on "quarter" and other words with /kw/.

Comment: The first dozen pertinent sites in a Google search for "dwarf" contains nothing but "w"-inclusive pronunciations, both written and spoken.  On the Forvo site, which gives multiple examples of people actually saying the word in their version of English, only one person sounds somewhat like there's no "w" sound, but upon closer inspection, it's just that the vowel sound she uses is not that far from the sound of the w, kind of like "dwoof".  So I think your question is based on a false assumption, that people actually leave out the "w" sound, like they do in "sword."

Comment: @StevenLittman: The information about Forvo is useful. But if no one uses the pronunciation without /w/, why does the Oxford English Dictionary list it?

Comment: @sumelic~ is your OED a paper version? In my online version, the audio file has a clearly audible "w" for both BrE an AE variations.

Comment: @RoaringFish: Not the audio file, the written transcription  /d(w)ɔrf/ has parentheses around the "w," indicating that it is optional.

Comment: What makes you think parenthsis means optional? It mean 'sometimes indistinguishable', usually meaning in fast or careless speech. The usual example is the second syllable schwa in *camera* which is not optional, but often becomes very difficult to distinguish. I can't say I have ever had difficulty distinguishing a /w/ in *dwarf* no matter who was uttering it, but I can imagine a "do-orf" pronunciation.

Comment: @RoaringFish: "Symbols in parentheses are used to denote elements that may be **omitted** either by individual speakers or in particular phonetic contexts: e.g. bottle / ˈbɒt(ə)l/, Mercian /ˈmзːʃ(ɪ)ən/, suit /s(j)uːt/, impromptu /ɪmˈprɒm(p)tjuː/, father /ˈfɑːðə(r)/" ([key to pronunciation](http://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-pronunciation/)). I pronounce "suit" as  /suːt/; I don't say /sjuːt/ with an indistinguishable glide. The glide is just not present for me. Parentheses generally indicate omission is possible, although not always for all speakers.

Comment: That is pretty much what I said. The point being that the indistinguishable elements are contextual, not optional.

Comment: @RoaringFish: Are you saying that for you, the <e> in *camera* is not silent? I find that bizarre. I'm perfectly capable of distinguishing 'cam-ra' from 'ca-me-ra', but only the former is an English word AFAIK. Where are you from?

Comment: Re: "This sound change seems to be recent and currently in progress": How can you tell?

Comment: @ruakh ~ for me, whether camera has two or three syllables depends mainly on register. This is certainly not unique to me. I am from north England, and I hear both versions. Quite a lot actually, as photography is my main hobby.

Comment: @ruakh: I'm not sure, but I'm basing that statement on the fact that the variants without /w/ are not generally transcribed in dictionaries. I guess it might be old and in progress, though.

Comment: Very often, when an individual repeatedly hears an altered pronunciation of some phoneme in multiple people, and it does not appear to correspond to some known accent, the error is in the hearing rather than the speaking.  Even when someone can "hear" the phoneme in "normal" form in most cases, they may actually be basing this perception on aspects of the sounds which most people do not consider to be significant, and ignoring the sounds other consider to be significant.  (I've no idea *why* this might be but I've observed signs of it here several times.)

Comment: I don’t recall ever hearing (or noticing) /dɔrf/, but I definitely recognise and frequently also produce /kɔrtər/. Unlike you, I also have no problem with /θɔrt/, though only in AmE. I do think some level of labialisedness of the preceding consonant tends to remain, though that may be true even in words that have no /w/, such as _court_ [kʷɔrt] and _Thor_ [θʷɔr].

Comment: @RoaringFish Symbols in parenthesis are absolutely _optional_; that is precisely what the parentheses mean. In some cases, to some people, the optionality is contextual, and it’s more a matter of an existing phoneme being indistinguishable or unarticulated in certain contexts; but that is far from always the case. To both me and ruakh, for instance, _camera_ always has two syllables to me (as to ruakh), never three: there simply is no schwa at all between /m/ and /r/, even in clear, articulate speech. The only difference between _camera_ and _Camry_ to me is the final vowel, /ə/ vs /ɪ/.

Comment: I don't know, but anyone that pronounces dwarf as "dorf" sounds like a dork to me.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any information on dropping the "w" in "dwarf" (maybe it's not common in this word after all!) but I did find out after asking this question that the [2003 Harvard Dialect Survey](http://dialect.redlog.net/), which involved speakers across the United States, had a question about the [pronunciation of "quarter"](http://dialect.redlog.net/). The breakdown across the U.S. was

> a. with [kw] (62.07%)
>
> b. with [k] ("cor-ter") (30.09%)
>
> c. I use both interchangeably (7.41%)
>
> d. other (0.43%)
>
> (10890 respondents)

I didn't see any geographical trends in the distribution of the different pronunciations.

Comment: The Harvard dialect survey has a breakdown by state. Taking a small sample of states, some people use it everywhere, but it looks like it's most prevalent in Maryland and West Virginia, but also common in Delaward, New Jersey, and Pennsylvania

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I've ever heard the "w" completely elided in "dwarf", but perhaps there might be some transitional process happening, as I do sometimes hear it pronounced "do-orf" (i.e. two syllables), especially by those who have a slower pace of speech. A bit like pronouncing "film" as "fil-um".

"Quarter" is different: I pronounce it with the "w" when I'm articulating my words, and unconsciously drop the "w" when I'm talking more lazily or colloquially - though after reading your question, I'm now much more conscious of doing so!

"Quart" isn't heard much now that we're metric in Australia but I think it gets the same treatment as "quarter". I'm not aware of any other word where the "w" sound is disappearing.

Comment: So you're from Australia? I guess it isn't restricted to American English then. Interestingly, I just found a source that says the /w/ sound can also be dropped from "quarter" and "quart" in New Zealand English: https://books.google.com/books?id=zNNCKcMml8MC&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=phonology+quarter+dropped+w&source=bl&ots=2MhgSGEol-&sig=K1OvOSzqlQCsTik4Sw-GeleL9i4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-3oiy58_LAhVGGh4KHfU-B_kQ6AEIOjAH#v=onepage&q=phonology%20quarter%20dropped%20w&f=false

Comment: I've also heard "quartz" without the /w/, so perhaps what this reflects is the similarity between the /w/ sound and the following /or/ sound, leading to the /w/ being elided in lazy pronunciation of these specific "quar" words.

Comment: Yes, that seems likely. But for some reason, I can't drop the /w/ in "quarry" and "quarantine," even though they have the vowel /or/ for me.